# How can I make a class method return a new instance of itself?

Tags: python

I have a python class which has a few lists and variables(initialized in `__init__`).

I want to have a method which operates upon this particular instances data and returns a new instance(new data). In the end, this method should return a new instance with modified data while leaving the original instance's data intact.

What is a pythonic way to do this?

EDIT:

I have a method in the class called `complement()` which modifies the data in a particular way. I would like to add a `__invert__()` method which returns an instance of the class with `complement()`ed data.

Example: Suppose I have a class A.
a=A()
a.complement() would modify the data in instance a.
b = ~a would leave the data in instance a unchanged but b will contain complement()ed data.

Comment: Class methods operate on the class, not on an instance.  What do you actually want to do?

Comment: your `def invert(self)` just needs to do something like `rval = ListsAndVariables()`, `... clone the data, complement it...`, `return rval`.  you probably shouldn't use `__invert__`, because that is for bitwise operations.  It's going to be confusing to many people to see what you're doing in there.

Answer (score 5):

I like to implement a `copy` method that creates an identical instance of the object. Then I can modify the values of that new instance as I please.

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x, self.y = x, y

    def copy(self):
        """
        create a new instance of Vector,
        with the same data as this instance.
        """
        return Vector(self.x, self.y)

    def normalized(self):
        """
        return a new instance of Vector,
        with the same angle as this instance,
        but with length 1.
        """
        ret = self.copy()
        ret.x /= self.magnitude()
        ret.y /= self.magnitude()
        return ret

    def magnitude(self):
        return math.hypot(self.x, self.y)
```

so in your case, you might define a method like:

```
def complemented(self):
    ret = self.copy()
    ret.__invert__()
    return ret
```

Comment: Don't put comments before the method; put a docstring inside the method.

Comment: What could be benefit/drawback of these two methods?

Answer (score 4):

the [copy](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) module can make a copy of a instance exactly like you whish:

```
def __invert__(self):
    ret = copy.deepcopy(self)
    ret.complemented()
    return ret
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean implementation of Factory design pattern in Python [example](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/python_programming/python_ch23.html#objects.creation.factory)